Why does xcode keep on crashing when I play the preview?
Heres my code
it just says preview crashed it was working earlier today i messed up that code so i restarted but the preview still wont work
//
//  OnboardingView.swift
//  Yapper
//
//  Created by Aarush Kamat on 6/27/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import RiveRuntime
struct OnboardingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RiveViewModel(fileName: "shapes").view()
    }
}

#Preview {
    OnboardingView()
}

I've tried reinstalling xcode and looking into more forums the never helped. And also I have two files OnboardingView.swift and content view, for now im putting my main code in the OnboardingView.swift

OnboardingView is irrelevant. Debug your code! In RiveViewModel comment out parts to detect the culprit. Often it's a missing dot in front of a view modifier.

but one question wheres the riveviewmodel sorry im new to rive and swiftUI

Highlight RiveViewModel and press ⌃⌘J

Select the stethoscope icon when Preview crashes as Rive may give a descriptive error message. Also check that shapes.riv is in your project. The string "shapes" must match the case of the file name.
